# Create SAML 2.0 assertion by existing element in OpenSAML

Tags: java, opensaml, ws-trust

I am trying to create an SAML 2.0 assertion with OpenSAML using an existing assertion element for a token renewal process.

```
 // Obtain the token
            Token tk = tkStorage.getToken(data.getTokenId());

            OMElement assertionOMElement = tk.getToken();
            int samlRstversion = data.getSamlRstVersion(); 
if(samlRstversion == 2) {
                    DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap();
                    UnmarshallerFactory unmarshallerFactory = Configuration.getUnmarshallerFactory();
                    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = unmarshallerFactory.getUnmarshaller((Element)assertionOMElement);
                    Element x1 = (Element)assertionOMElement;
                    Assertion samlAssertion = (Assertion) unmarshaller
                            .unmarshall(x1);
    //Add conditions to the assertion
}
```

I'm getting two errors.

1. When the `DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap();` is used, it throws an
   exception `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This parser does not support specification "null" version "null"`
2. When `DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap()` is removed it throws at
   Assertion samlAssertion = `(Assertion) unmarshaller.unmarshall(x1);`

Is there something that I have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two errors which caused the exception. Of course the `bootsrap()` had to be done in order to continue with marshalling or unmarshalling.

1. In a previous line of the code the `DOM` implementation was changing to `DOOM`. 
   `DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.setDOOMRequired(true);`
   Even though it was [deprecated](http://people.apache.org/~veithen/axiom/apidocs/org/apache/axiom/om/impl/dom/jaxp/DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.html) the code was using it. So before do `bootstrap()` it had to be set to `false` since the underlying JAXB implementation uses the DOM.
2. Also, casting `OMElement assertionOMElement` to `Element` threw this exception. `org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces.`

Solution was to convert the `OMElement` to `String` and then build the `Document` from it and get the `DocumentElement`

```
String s = assertionOMElement.toString();
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = docBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(s.trim().getBytes()));
Element element = document.getDocumentElement();
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you always have to run the bootstrap or else you get errors.

It seams like the first error is because you have a too old implementation of JAXP 
https://lists.internet2.edu/sympa/arc/mace-opensaml-users/2010-01/msg00015.html

The OpenSAML team suggests using Apache Xerces or Xalan.